# 'Head First Design Patterns: Decorator example IS-A and HAS-A confusion

Tags: java, inheritance, uml, decorator, abstract

I'm trying to get my head around design patterns. I think they may be one step too advanced in my programming abilities as I am struggling quite a bit with them, however my university assignment is to apply them. So here I am.

I am going through the example of the Decorator Pattern from the Head First book. This is the example:

[image: Head First Design Patterns: Decorator UML]

As you can see in the diagram, the **CondimentDecorator** has the IS-A and HAS-A relationship with **Beverage**. However, here is the code they write for the **CondimentDecorator** and one of the condiments, **Mocha**:

[image: CondimentsDecorator]

[image: Mocha]

In the **CondimentDecorator** class the only thing that it contains is a method *getDescription*.

It's the **Mocha** class that contains instantiates the **Beverage** class AND calls *getDescription*.

So doesn't this mean that it's the **Mocha** class that has a IS-A and a HAS-A relationship?

Comment: From the UML-diagram: any Mocha IS-A CondimentDecorator and any CondimentDecorator IS-A Beverage and HAS-A Beverage which plays the role of a 'component' to the CondimentDescriptor.

Comment: The mocha class has the association to Beverage (HAS-A) the generalization is still owned by the CondimentDecorator (although there is a legitimate question whether or not a condimentDecorator should actually be a drink)

Comment: @Mihe correct, that's what the diagram says, but the code seems to contradict that statement. There is no association from CondimentDecorator to Beverage in the code.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I don't think that choosing coffees as an example was the simplest and clearest way to do this for the reason that you said - having condimentDecorator as a drink. In looking up other examples I came across this site (https://www.baeldung.com/java-decorator-pattern) which uses a Christmas Tree to decorate. Much more fitting! However I couldn't get that code to work, but that's a separate questions entirely.

Comment: @Mihe when looking only at the UML diagram I understand the relationship. However it's looking at the code that confuses me. I don't see how the UML diagram and code match up. From what I understand, the code only suggests an IS-A relationship between Beverage and CondimentDecorator, and that Mocha has both IS-A and a HAS-A relationship.

Comment: Yes, it's confusing and I don't think, that the example from the book is a good one in terms of clarity. An association describes a semantic relationship. Semantically, I'd interpret this as a HAS-A relationship, although this association is implemented by an attribute in every single subclass. Perhaps there's someone out there who can shed some more light into the darkness.

Answer (score 0):

The decorator pattern is indeed not easy to grasp when learning OOP: it uses inheritance and [object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) together to offer something that looks like dynamic inheritance but is mostly based on composition.  In addition, the example uses several levels of inheritance, which makes it even more complex to grasp.

The idea in this design, is twofold:

- a `Mocha` is a `CondimentDecorator` that you can use it everywhere where a `CondimentDecorator`  is expected.  Moreover, since a `CondimentDecorator` is a `Beverage`, you can also use a `Mocha` everywhere where a `Beverage` is expected.  This is the purpose of the inheritance in this design (IS-A).
- a `CondimentDecorator` object (such as a particular `Mocha`) knows a `Beverage` object that it enriches with additional responsibilities, acting as intermediary: it deals a "front-end" to the external world, and enriches the behavior of the other objects by doing additional things in addition to forwarding calls.  This is the purpose of the association which is implemented in a code with [object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)  (i.e. `Beverage beverage`) - (HAS-A, but this terminology might be misleading).

In consequence, we can observe the following:

- The `Mocha` class inherits the HAS-A and the IS-A relationships from the `CondimentDecorator`. These inherited relationships are not added in the UML diagram.
- The `Mocha` class has no additional HAS-A relationship
- The `Mocha` class must implement its own `getDescription()` , since it inherits directly from the `CondimentDecorator` which makes it abstract, whereas the `Beverage` provides a default implementation.
- An instance of `Mocha`, e.g. an object `Mocha aMochaInCup2987662 = new Mocha(aHouseBlendInCup2987662);` is itself at the same time a `Beverage`  a `CondimentDecorator` and a `Mocha` and has internally all the features provided by the three classes even if they are not all visible/accessible.